# How should I be testing a super simple front-end app built with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower

I followed these steps to set up a very simple starter frontend app:

```
- $ yo (Webapp Generator no css frameworks)
- $ bower install -S underscore
- add _.times(3, function () { console.log('rawr') });
- $ grunt
```

**expected result:**

```
everything runs fine.
```

**Actual result:**

```
grunt aborts due to warnings. ('_' is not defined.)
grunt server runs fine and '_' is properly defined
```

2 Question:

```
- What should I be doing to make grunt happy?
- How should I be testing this kind of setup? (bower install jasmine?)
```

I'm looking for new workflows for quickly setting up simple front-end application. For a while I've been setting everything up manually, and I'm trying to expand my skills.